# How to override/discover CMD/ENTRYPOINT for base image

Tags: docker, docker-build, docker-run, docker-entrypoint

Say I have this:

```
FROM oresoftware/lmx-broker:0.2.1

ENTRYPOINT ['/docker-entrypoint.sh']
```

if I don't use `CMD` will `CMD` default to the value set in the base image? Will my use of `ENTRYPOINT` override the `ENTRYPOINT` in the base image? Will my use of `CMD` override the `CMD` in the base image?

Basically my goal is to override the ENTRYPOINT of the base image, but be able to discover/reuse the CMD, so that my `docker-entrypoint.sh` file will look like:

```
#!/bin/sh

"$@" | capture-stdio
```

where "$@" would default to CMD from the base image.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:

> Note: If CMD is defined from the base image, setting ENTRYPOINT will reset CMD to an empty value. 
>   In this scenario, CMD must be defined in the current image to have a value.

So to answer your question this won't work. 
[To read more](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

Good luck.

Comment: that's a shame, because then users have to go discover what the CMD value is in the base image, and replicate it

Answer (score 1):

If you use `ENTRYPOINT ['/docker-entrypoint.sh']` in your Dockerfile, it will override the entrypoint.

In simple word, if you use anything that is defined in base image and you redefined in your image, it will be override either its `CMD` or `entrypoint` or any other configuration like `ENV` etc.

Once you define entrypoint in your Dockerfile, any thing pass to `CMD` will be consider as a argument to entrypoint.

To view the `CMD` and `entrypoint` of the base image just run

```
docker inspect oresoftware/lmx-broker:0.2.1
```

or to view the entrypoint of base image

```
docker run --rm oresoftware/lmx-broker:0.2.1 bash -c "cat path_to_entrypoint"
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question arises as follows. Suppose you do this, and then you want to invoke the `ENTRYPOINT` and/or `CMD` of your parent image, but you pull that image from somewhere else, so they might change. Now how to do that? You'll need to dynamically figure out what they are.